# Why can't I update this table with the same code used in another place using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

The table cell updates correctly to "" (empty) in the changeScore function, but that same cell does not change at all in the editUpdate function when I try to place the new score in there.  It just stays empty.  Any ideas?

```
function changeScore(playerKey)
{
    var table = document.getElementById("scoreTable");

    players[playerKey].score = players[playerKey].oldScore;
    table.rows[currentRound - 1].cells[playerKey + 1].innerHTM = '';

    document.getElementById('inputArea').innerHTML = '<font size="6">Did <b>' + players[playerKey].name + '</b> take <b>' + players[playerKey].bid + '</b> trick(s)?</font><br /><button value="Yes" id="yesButton" onclick="editUpdate(' + playerKey + ', \'yes\')">Yes</button>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<button value="No" id="noButton" onclick="editUpdate(' + playerKey + ', \'no\')">No</button>';
}

function editUpdate(thePlayerKey, answer)
{
    var table = document.getElementById("scoreTable");

    players[thePlayerKey].oldScore = players[thePlayerKey].score;

    if (answer == "yes"){
        **
    }else{
        **
    }

    table.rows[currentRound - 1].cells[thePlayerKey + 1].innerHTM = '<font color="' + players[thePlayerKey].font + '">' + players[thePlayerKey].score + '</font>';

    document.getElementById('inputArea').innerHTML = '<button onclick="startRound()">Start Round</button>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<button onclick="edit()">Edit Scores</button>';

}
```

Comment: Should it be ``innerHTML`` or is ``innerHTM`` correct? If in doubt, try innerHTML.

Comment: Do you have the typo `innerHTM` in the original code, or is that just a copying error?

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot.  Yes, changing to innerHTML worked.  Weird that the typo worked fine in the changeScore function, but not in the editUpdate function.  That's what had me going in circles.  Thanks for the quick help Winestone and Barmar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTM` should be `innerHTML`

This:

```
table.rows[currentRound - 1].cells[playerKey + 1].innerHTM = '';
```

Should be:

```
table.rows[currentRound - 1].cells[playerKey + 1].innerHTML = '';
```

(Same for 2nd function)